# The area of the orthogonal projected of ellipsoid?

Tags: geometry

I want to know what is wrong in the way of making 
the formula of the orthogonal projected area of ellipsoid: (x/A)^2+(y/B)^2+(z/C)^2=1 to the plane which has a vertical vector (a,b,c)
[image]
[image]
[image]